# How does sfc utility check file integrity?

Tags: windows, compression, data-integrity

We know that, in Windows OS, sfc is a well-known utility that checks for the integrity of critical system files.

If changes are found, they are replaced by compressed files in Wsxs folder or the like.

But, a naive hacker may replace the compressed version (by booting in Linux and then write to the Windows partition).

So, it is unclear to me how sfc can securely check for a system file's integrity. Say, the hacker can change both the current svchost.exe file and its archived version.

Comment: SFC checks file's CRC which original value is stored in .cat file which content is protected by certificate. The file which should be copied when existing file damage detected is checked too. Hacker cries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It is unclear to me how SFC can securely check for a system file's integrity.

SFC is part of WFP (Windows File Protection).

It uses file signatures and catalog files generated by code signing to check whether files have been modified/corrupted and code signing.

Of course this does not prevent hackers from booting in Linux and then write to the Windows partition, but it does provide a repair mechanism that ensures all critical Windows files are the correct versions.

Remember all bets are off if a hacker has physical access to a machine. If this occurs nothing can prevent a hacker from doing what they want.

> WFP protects critical system files that are installed as part of Windows (for example, files with a .dll, .exe, .ocx, and .sys extension and some True Type fonts). WFP uses the file signatures and catalog files that are generated by code signing to verify if protected system files are the correct Microsoft versions.
>
> Replacement of protected system files is supported only through the
>   following mechanisms:
>
> - Windows Service Pack installation using Update.exe
> - Hotfixes installed using Hotfix.exe or Update.exe
> - Operating system upgrades using Winnt32.exe
> - Windows Update

...

> The WFP feature provides protection for system files using two mechanisms. The first mechanism runs in the background. This protection is triggered after WFP receives a directory change notification for a file in a protected directory. After WFP receives this notification, WFP determines which file was changed. If the file is protected, WFP looks up the file signature in a catalog file to determine if the new file is the correct version. If the file is not the correct version, WFP replaces the new file with the file from the cache folder (if it is in the cache folder) or from the installation source.

...

> The second protection mechanism that is provided by the WFP feature is the System File Checker (Sfc.exe) tool. At the end of GUI-mode Setup, the System File Checker tool scans all the protected files to make sure that they are not modified by programs that were installed by using an unattended installation. The System File Checker tool also checks all the catalog files that are used to track correct file versions. If any of the catalog files are missing or damaged, WFP renames the affected catalog file and retrieves a cached version of that file from the cache folder. If a cached copy of the catalog file is not available in the cache folder, the WFP feature requests the appropriate media to retrieve a new copy of the catalog file.

Source [Description of the Windows File Protection feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/222193/description-of-the-windows-file-protection-feature)